# What is the correct way to access a local Sqlite3 DB from my Electron app?

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, electron

I'm trying to create an Electron application using React that will be able to insert and pull data from a local sqlite3 database. I have tried to set up a Web Worker to handle the database interactions but whenever I create an new database connection, the developer tools window disconnects and nothing happens within the app. I think there must be some error happening somewhere that I am unable to see or catch.

Do I have to use a Web Worker or a similar threading/processing tool? If I need to use a Web Worker, what would cause this issue?

I have tried to include the sqlite3 package in one of my React components (without the Web Worker) but that throws all kinds of errors.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly possible to access/use sqlite from the renderer process.

We have a huge complex app communicating with dozens of USB hardware devices via native drivers and everything is running in a single renderer process. To do this we just ensure that no code makes synchronous calls.

I've not used sqlite myself but [`node-sqlite3`](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3) says its fully asynchronous, so you can use it from the Electron renderer without blocking the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up scrapping the web workers as apparently they don't work at all. Swapped over to doing the inserts and queries in the main process and sending the results back to the render process using Electron's build in IPC.

Comment: Just be aware that blocking in the main process can hang the renderers too. The renderers communicate with the GPU process via the main process so if you block in the main process for 500ms you'll notice issues in the renderers too...